# Using dplyr filter in a function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following function:

```
library(dplyr)

filter <- function(aNumber) {

  x <- as.numeric(aNumber)

   # create df
    num <- c(2,3,4)
    tekst <- c("part1", "part2", "part3")
    df2 <- data.frame(num,tekst)

    #filter with parameter
    df2 <- filter(df, num == x)

}
```

If I try to run using filter(2) it trows an error however. I get:

```
 Error in filter(df, num == x) : unused argument (num == x)
```

Any thoughts on why i get this error? I dont get it....

Comment: 1. filter is already a function, don't overwrite it. You seem to have created a filter-function, that calls (dplyrs?) filter. So, there is no argument 'num' (only argument'aNumber') in your function.

Comment: besides, why use the dplyr filter in your function when df[num == x, ] also works? Btw where is df coming from? Typo?

Answer (score 4):

You called your function filter, so I would imagine that the last line of your function is recursively calling itself. You can replace it with

```
df2 <- dplyr::filter(df, num == x)
```

Regardless, you should probably rename your function. Try to choose function names that won't clash with those in R (or in packages that you import).

Comment: renaming the function is better practice.

Comment: I agree. Edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @tomr thanks for feedback. I tried it but then I got the following error: Error: incorrect length (3), expecting: 9. Does it work for you? Also when I rename my function to filter_it I still get an error

Comment: Amusing that you suggest choosing function names that don't clash as you're discussing `dplyr::filter`, since it masks `stats::filter`. I agree with you. I just like the irony.

Comment: @MarcvanderPeet, You have other errors that are preventing it from working. Your 7th line should probably be "df <- data.frame(num,tekst)", not df2. You may still have a function name masked, so I would explicitly call dplyr::filter as suggested in my answer. Finally, your function does not seem to return anything. When I made those changes, it works for me.